# uploading an array to server in swift using Alamofire

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

This is how I'm saving the data successfully to model class when user login

```
var isLogin: IsLogin!
var loginDetail: LoginDetail!
var myDetail: MyDetail!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do{
    isLogin = try decoder.decode(IsLogin.self, from: response.data!)
    loginDetail = isLogin.success
    myDetail = loginDetail.user
}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

here is my model class where I'm saving response from the request

```
struct IsLogin: Decodable {
    var success: LoginDetail
}
struct LoginDetail: Decodable {
    var user: MyDetail
}

struct MyDetail: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var emergency_contacts: [EmergencyContacts]?
}
struct EmergencyContacts: Decodable {
    var user_id : Int
    var number : String
}
```

I want to post EmergencyContacts in another request how do I do that? This is how im trying but in response array of EmergencyContacts is always empty

```
multipartFormData.append("\(myDetail.emergency_contacts!)".data(using: .utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!,
`enter code here`withName: "emergency_contacts")
```

I have print all the values from model class and they are fine but guide me about how to send an array in a post request.Please suggest my some method using multipartformdara because I have been using this to send other parameters as well.below is the postman screenshot where If I send parameters like this then I can get the emergencycontacts in response 13 is the id of emergency contact
[image]

Comment: You want to send the array as a JSON?

Comment: @gcharita in the form of array the api.txt file says this-->
 emergency_contacts (sample array=>{[0]=>12, [1]=>13})

Comment: Since im new to this im struggling to understand

Comment: hi, try to check if the server expects body parameters. Sometimes backend developers do a POST requests with query parameters instead of body paramters

Comment: @AlexanderNikolaychuk when I do this on postman emergency_contacts[] and the value is some id e.g 10 the call is successfull and I can have the emergency contact at that id.

Comment: can you share POSTMAN screen with this data?

Comment: @AlexanderNikolaychuk please check now

Comment: On screen you have only ID 13. In your code you have codable struct which will be codabled as object. Can you print myDetail.emergenycontacts, This value which are you trying to send in this key?